# Foreach inside a Form::select in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I try to walk a variable using the helpers of Laravel but it trhows an error, and when I do the same with html tags it works correctly.

```
{{ Form::select('categoria', array(
        @foreach($enlaceid as $categoria) 
          $categoria->id => $categoria->nombre  {{-- I tryed too with englobing with {{ }}
      )) }} 
      @endforeach

    <select name="categoria">
        @foreach($enlaceid as $categoria) 
        <option value= " {{ $categoria->id }} "> {{$categoria->nombre}} </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

Comment: What is this?: `$categoria->id => $categoria->nombre`. What are you trying to do with it? I don't see you using any helpers in this line.

Comment: L4 Form helper for select tags works fine with just an array no need to do foreach, just pass the array with key=>value pair and it will set the options

Answer (score 5):

Use the `lists()` method and pass that to your `Form::select()` method. Like so:

```
$categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');
```

In your view:

```
{{ Form::select('category_id', $categories) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

for you want to use foreach laravelcollective  in laravel 5.2 or above, you can use same as @garethDaine but above laravel 5.2, you using `pluck()` instead `lists()` because `lists()` function was depracated in laravel 5.2.

so in the examples is:

```
$banks = Bank::pluck('name', 'id');
```

instead

```
$banks = Bank::lists('name', 'id');
```

then in your view form:

```
{!! Form::select('bank_id', $banks, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

---

Note: 1st array in you pluck() will be name display on you `<option>` and second will be `value="1"` as example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Gareth Daine edited by Drew Hammond worked for me, with a slight edit

My Controller

```
$category = Category::all();
```

My View

```
{!! Form::select('category_id', $categories->pluck('name', 'id')) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add a default value also to your options you need to do this:

```
$categories = Category::lists('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

In your view:

```
{{ Form::select('category_id', array('0' => 'Default') + $categories) }}
```